# GWT Long type from API for Date parsing?

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to deserialize a json api which is sending down timestamps as long types. My overlay looks like this:

```
public class OverlayTest extends JavaScriptObject {
    public final native Long getTimestamp() /*-{ return this.timestamp; }-*/;
}
```

which seems to work - when I use the getter for printing to console, I get the long value ok. I'm trying to pass that into a Date instance now for formatting:

```
OverlayTest item = ...;
Date date = new Date(item.getTimestamp());
// or
Date date = new Date(item.getTimestamp().longValue());
```

but I'm getting a TypeError exception as:

```
longValue__J is not a function
```

the output stacktrace is a bit mangled since the GWT output is already compiled to javascript in my case. I know that GWT is somehow emulating Long support since javascript can't do it directly - is there some workaround for this, or will this just not be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `java.lang.Long` (or `long`) is emulated in GWT, since JS cannot properly handle this type - all numbers in JS are effectively Java doubles, with only about 54 bits of precision, while a `long`/`Long` needs 64 bits. If GWT lets you pass numbers in and out of JS as longs, you would lose precision.

In your GWT code, an object wrapping three numbers is used to represent a long correctly. Any JS code that expects to see a number is going to be very surprised to see that object, and Java code is going to be surprised to see a number instead of that wrapper object.

So instead, either pass `double`s and `int`s in and out of JSNI. In that case of passing millis for a date, an `int` will work fine until 2038 or so. Maybe by then we'll have reasonably sized numbers in our browsers.

Even if you had a very long number in your JS code, it would be silently truncated so that it fit within what JS could correctly represent, so you aren't losing anything. It would be better if you could keep the data in `long` the whole time, but if the number passes through JS (other than as a String), precision will be lost of the number is big enough. But of course if your numbers won't get that big, `double` or `int` will be sufficient for you.

(I don't know why it is appearing to work correctly - by guess is that the emulated object has a nice `toString`, but without specifics of how you got it to 'work', I can't be sure what happened.)

Comment: Ok thanks I see - so the most correct option is to do something like pass down the timestamp in a string format like ISO 8601?

Comment: Yes, or don't go further into the future than 2038, or pass the long number itself as a String, and use Long.parseLong to get it.